# Confused about the file

Tags: wordpress, web

How do I figure out what is going on with this file?

http://busyfast.com/saadrtawegfaVaAWERWF/htaccess_wkbl_test_20180503.txt

I was given no explanation regarding this file and I could be overthinking but am at a loss. I am still new to this subject and really want to thoroughly understand all of it.

Answer (score 1):

@Lyz Allen,

The .htaccess file is an Apache server configuration file located in the root directory of your website files.

These are server base options, and WordPress can write to this file. Optimization and security plugins will add/edit this file. You can write rules and access files and directories with this file.

I have included a reference on `.htaccess` configurations.

Here is a reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Apache_Configuration_htaccess

Hope this helps.